# Attached garage with brick exterior facade

Tags: framing, brick

I have an attached garage with a brick veneer exterior on 3 sides.   The interior walls that were behind the brick walls have completely rotted out and are not structurally sound.  At current, one wall is completely gone while the others are compromised.  The 100 year old house has galvanized tabs in the mortar bed of the brick and looks like they were used to support the brick as it was installed up the wall and attached to the studs.  How can I rebuild the interior walls and attach or support the brick from the inside?  Or reattach the tabs from the inside?  Or is it not necessary?  The structural integrity of the brick is good and sound.  The vertical height of the exterior walls of brick are about 20 feet.  I will need to redo all 3 walls.  I want to try and avoid tearing down the facade of the garage, but I think the brick needs to be attached to the new walls?

Comment: Brick veneer on rotted walls should not be solid.  Rotted walls should show signs of the building starting to lean/collapse.  Galvanized tabs in rotted walls should be gone.  Rot usually needs moisture, so fixing that first might be good.

Comment: Some pictures of the damage would help people give you an assessment, but you may need to get someone hands on to determine what the best course of action may be.